# In Python. How to make the elements of the first list be the keys, and the elements of the second list the values ​of the dictionary

Tags: python

help me please
In Python. How to make the elements of the first list be the keys, and the elements of the second list the values ​​of the dictionary

```
keys = []  # first list


values = [] # second list


dictionary = {} # our dict
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with `zip()`, then create the `dict` from a list of tuples:

```
dictionary = dict(zip(keys, values))
```